# How to set the ic_drawer.png icon on android navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

```
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, 
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, 
                R.string.drawer_open, 
                R.string.drawer_close) { ... }
```

Okay, I double checked R.drawable.ic_drawer a few times. It is an icon with 3 bars, but my android display a left arrow. Anyone know what's wrong and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: replace the file `ic_drawer.png` to something that is NOT a left arrow

Comment: read this http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Comment: It doesn't show drawer icon or it doesn't react on click? Did you call setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer); and initialize mDrawerLayout before putting it inside mDrawerToggle with something like mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); ?

Answer (score 0):

Call syncState() from your Activity's onPostCreate to synchronize the indicator with the state of the linked DrawerLayout.

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Additionally onConfigurationChanged should be called on the ActionBarDrawerToggle, include this in your Activity:

```
    @Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your NavigationDrawerfragment class go to setUp method and do something like this with actionbar to set actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator() to ic_drawer just like below. It will remove back button and replace with ic_drawer button

```java
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_drawer);
}
```